# Unable to record SAP BPC with loadrunner or fiddler

Tags: fiddler, loadrunner, sap-erp, netweaver, sap-bw

I have an issue while recording SAP BPC10 accessing with NetWeaver with loadrunner 12.55.

While recording, the event count is getting increased and I am able to navigate through application (excel sheet) but once the recording is stopped nothing is getting generated.

Similar issue with fiddler as well, it is not capturing any traffic. Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue and how it got resolved. Thanks in advance.

I tried changing proxy settings and also there is no firewall placed in between my machine and server. I have followed SAP document as well (https://www.sap.com/documents/2015/08/008b8186-547c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html)

Answer (score 0):

Record Winsock, see if you receive anything.  If so, but not using Fiddler or an HTTP Virtual User, then you simply need to record a different protocol or use a different generation path, such as  a Citrix/RDP/GUI virtual user to run excel.

Alternate path, grab Wireshark/Ethereal to take a look at the protocols expressed between your Excel add in and the next upstream architectural component for insight into how you should be developing your test code.

Comment: Thanks James, I tried recording in Winsock and found that there is some communication. I have also raised a service ticket with Micro focus and waiting for their feedback.

Comment: But what port and what protocol?   That makes a huge difference as you appear to be recording HTTP.

Comment: Yes James, I am trying to record using web(http/html) protocol using windows application as recording mode to invoke excel. I think it is HTTP but not HTTPS but not sure on the server communication.

Comment: What makes you believe that HTTP is the carrier protocol between excel and the next upstream architectural component?  I would suggest that it is more likely not HTTP.   Support is not there to provide consulting on the proper protocol to select, but on usability and defects

Comment: Hi James, Thanks and apologies for late reply. I got to know from SAP that the communication protocol is Remote Function Call (RFC) between the excel and server. could you let me know if you have any thoughts on how to record this type of communication with Loadrunner please?

Comment: What port, what protocol?  VBA virtual user to reproduce the function call in VBA inside of excel?   GUI Virtual user.  Citrix Virtual User.  RDP Virtual User